# Project starts debugging when I build the project

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with a setup project and a "main project".
When I build the setup project, I also build the main project to be sure I create the setup for the latest build.
The setup project is a InstallShield LE project, and everything works as expected once the build is finished.
The problem is that the main project starts running when I build the setup project. This makes the build of the setup project halt until I stop the main project.
Is there a setting somewhere to prevent this?

The main project does not start when I build the main project, only when I build the setup project.

Edit, updated with recent findings:
It seems to happen on "Extracting COM data from 1 component(s)". Does this mean that I can't prevent it, because InstallShield needs to start the program to extract COM data?

Comment: Use Build > Configuration Manager and untick the setup project for the Debug configuration.  When you're done testing and ready to build the Release configuration and setup project, be sure to use Build > Build instead of pressing F5.

Comment: Nope. For some reason the main project is launched (twice) when VS is building the setup project. (The main project is built first). It seems to happen on "Extracting COM data from 1 component(s)". Does this mean that I can't prevent it, because InstallShield needs to start the program to extract COM data?

Comment: That's possible, I know that WIX can harvest registry keys that way.  Maybe IS as well, hmm.  The point of my recommendation is that you just don't care that it does this when you configure the build correctly.